# ActiveRecord offset followed by average

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, offset

For example, I have few `Example` objects in database.

```
#<Example id: 1, some_field: 3>      
#<Example id: 2, some_field: 10>
#<Example id: 3, some_field: 4>
```

Say, I want every object except freshest. What I do is

```
examples = Example.order('created_at desc').offset(1)
```

to get them.

I then want to find out average of `some_field` among those 2 objects (object 1 and object 2). I do

```
examples.average(:some_field)
```

I then get nil cause SQL is something like

```
SELECT AVG("examples"."some_field") AS avg_id FROM "examples" OFFSET 1
```

It seems that what happens is that offset is applied after average calculation.
Solution I use is casting collection to array and operating the array.
But I wonder, is there any way to perform that in ActiveRecord style with AR relations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way to accomplish it.  And you could expand it to include other rows you have no interest in calculating.

```
freshest_id = Example.order(:id :desc).first
Example.where.not(id: freshest_id).average(:some_field)
```